# 'C:\Users...' is not recognized as an internal command when starting a project with Yarn

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to start a project with Yarn using the command `yarn create react-app ReportingApp --template typescript` however it says that my user is not recognized:

[image]

I also tried adding the path in my windows variables (path). However, I still get the error.

I saw this issue in the past and I fixed it by replacing my user name "Gabriel Donada" with the user ID from Windows, but I have not found how to make that again.

Comment: Remember to not show pictures of text, just show that text, in code fences or using code formatting. That said: you want to report this to `create-react-app` who then may send you on to report it to `yarn` instead, but something isn't checking to see if it's running on Windows, where you _must_ wrap dir locations with spaces in double quotes for it to be treated as "one thing" instead of multiple whitespace-separated arguments.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work for Yarn only. I have created using npx `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` as a workaround and worked fine. For some reason, Yarn is not working. I have uninstalled and installed back and still same issue. Probably is something with my windows variables.

Comment: the combination of `yarn` and `create-react-app` does not seem to be able to deal with paths that contain a space ...

Comment: So again: that's a bug and the maintainers of create-react-app and/or yarn should be told. That's how we collectively improve open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened, but I used as workaround start the app using `npx create react-app ReportingApp --template typescript`